# Applying for Schengen Visa while near I-20 expiration. Would it affect my application?

Tags: schengen, f1-visas

I am an international student on F-1 Visa in the US. Does the Schengen Visa application require my I-20 to be valid for a minimum of 3 months after the travel end date?

From the consulate website

> Alien Residence Card (Green-Card) or residence visa valid in USA with I-20/IAP-66 (except B-1, B-2), those documents must be valid for a minimum of three months from the expiration date of your visa.

It is not clear to me whether the 3-month requirement is only for the F-1 Visa or if it includes I-20 as well. In my case, my F-1 visa would be valid for the 3 months after my Europe travel but my I-20 would not be.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you plan to return to the US after your trip to wherever you are going? Under what status?

Comment: Yes, I plan to return after the trip. My I-20 will still be valid at the time of return but it expires 2 months after that. So my reentry part is fine but I'm concerned whether this will prohibit me from obtaining the Schengen visa in the first place

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since it seems that a valid I-20 is needed to re-enter the United States, it forms a part of the **travel document** that the Schengen Code requires to be valid 3 months after the expected exit from the Schengen Area.

So if your travel itinerary includes a return back to the United States, then the conditions of **Article 6 (1)(a)(i)** of the Schengen Code must be fulfilled.

---

The wording of your quote (which I found at a [Spanish Consulate](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/BOSTON/en/ServiciosConsulares/ConsularServicesBoston/Pages/Visas.aspx) site) is slightly different than that of the [Visa requirements pdf of the German Missions in the United States](https://www.germany.info/blob/2108186/1f7619dde40b70592187fd3aed92125c/schengen-visa-requirements-data.pdf), where **plus endorsed I-20** is stated and no meantion that the F-1 must be valid for a further 3 months.

The **Schengen Code** does not deal with the details of what is considered a valid foreign residence permit for reentry into that country.

The **Schengen Code** does require that the persons **travel document** must be valid to return after that person's visit **plus 3 months** (**Article 6 (1)(a)(i)**).

Based on the [Wikipedia I-20 (form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-20_(form)) article, a valid I-20 is needed to reenter the United States. So the I-20 will be considered part of the **travel document**.

---

> **Schengen VISA (all stays of up to 90 days)**
>   ...
>
> - Original of valid US alien registration card or **valid US resident visa** (type A, E, **F plus endorsed I-20**, G, H, I, J plus J1 document, L, O, R) and one copy

---

> **Travel and travel signatures**
>   Whenever the student re-enters the United States after traveling, the student must have all of these at the time of arrival at the port of entry:
>
> - A valid passport (valid for at least six more months)
> - A valid F or M visa
> - A valid I-20 (i.e., an **I-20 whose program end date has not yet arrived**)
> - A travel signature on the I-20 (page 3) from the DSO that is at most one year old (six months in the case of students currently on post-completion Optional Practical Training)
>
> ...

---

**Sources**:

- [PDF Schengen VISA - German Missions in the United States](https://www.germany.info/blob/2108186/1f7619dde40b70592187fd3aed92125c/schengen-visa-requirements-data.pdf)
- [Spain - Boston Visas](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/BOSTON/en/ServiciosConsulares/ConsularServicesBoston/Pages/Visas.aspx)
- [I-20 (form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-20_(form))

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. To clarify, I will have a valid I-20 at the time of my return to the US after the trip but it expires in *2 months* from then. And according to your answer, this means that the Schengen Consulate will not be accepting my application since the I-20 will not be valid in three months from the end of my trip?

Comment: @AyushSharma Or they may issue a visa that expires 3 months before the I-20 expires.

Comment: Ah, but my trip ends on 3/29 (two months before my I-20 expires) and my dates, unfortunately, aren't flexible. In this case, they can't issue a visa expiring 3 months before. Do you think there is any way for me to make this trip possible? Thank you.

Comment: @AyushSharma Since it is a rule that is written directly into the Schengen Border Code, no. I suppose getting the I-20 extended another month is not an option? In this matter the consulate officials will probably not have any other option.

Comment: I am going to look into extending the I-20 for another month. Really thankful for the detailed answers. This is my first time posting here and I'm blown away at how prompt and thoughtful the answers are!

Comment: @AyushSharma Inform us of the result. I would be interested in learning if changes to the I-20 entail an extra fee or if the initial fee is a one time fee.

Comment: I have updated my I-20 for CPT and program change (undergrad to Master) with no extra fee, but these are standard changes. I would guess that an extension does not require fee either. What does a require a fee is getting an OPT recommendation on an I-20. I'm going to be doing that soon and will have to pay the international office $150.